# Display bug (a blank column) in new Gmail (browser version) found

Tags: gmail

In the new Gmail (browser version) I have a blank column on the right, between the emails list and the column with the calendar, keep and tasks icons. I found in the doom that the class AO assigns a margin-right:220px to the container div and if I remove it, everything works fine.

It happens in all my browsers (Win + Mac -> Chrome, Firefox), I loggend out, cleared the Local/Session Storage, IndexedDB and Cookies but nothing...

I attached the snapshot to be more clear. Thank You!

Blank column in Gmail displayed (browser version):
[image: blank column in Gmail displayed (browser version)]

Snapshot with add on top and blank right column:
[image: snapshot with add on top and blank right column]

Comment: Well first, what's your question? Second, I believe it's where ads are supposed to be, when you don't have an adblock

Comment: I don't have an adBlock... I always see the ads in top of the emails list (photo attached). The question is why this empty white column? I see snapshots of other people's new Gmail and is not there.... When I switch  back to old Gmail it disapears... Anyway, thank you for your response.

Comment: Well I'm not quite sure ads and "promotions" are the same thing... Isn't there a "premium" version of Gmail or something alike? Also, did you try to inspect the blank column itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem of the white space column! Previously of this new Gmail version I had installed the Chrome extension "RightTasks for Gmail™" ( https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/righttasks-for-gmail/hgniockidojcaaolfcbbkaaakbjdebpe ).

With the new version of Gmail it does not work anymore but it maintain the column where is supposed to show the tasks!